# SQL compare two columns with slight differences in data

Tags: sql

I have two tables on different servers and I need to link a column that they have in common. However, the data from the columns are sightly different.

I have 2 tables, one is a temporary table where I have the list of students I need with their full names, dob, address and the after school programs they attend to, and program ID, each program has an id. Another table has all the programs information with their ID and locations that are currently live in our system.

The other table has all the IDs but this data is 5 characters long and not all but most of the data end with a '0'. Now I need to join this table that has the 5 characters long data on my 1st table and say this ID belongs to this ID on my table with all my students.

Table **#students**:

```
StudentID  Lastname      Firstname       dob         Afterschool_program     location         Department     programID 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
81EB       Toreros     Christian         03/26/1999  Teen Dance Exercise     158-Bayshore    Theater            5269  
89EB       Willis      Michael           03/15/2002  Arts Painting  158-Mulan Drive    Arts          6985
```

Other table **Locations**:

```
 locationName                                                          Address                            LocationID
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------          
    Bay Shore - DAY Program / Scie- TEEN & YOUNG ADULTS - 52690           BayShore 123-89 place                  52690   
Mulan - DAY Program / Arts- TEEN - 96850           BayShore 123-89 place                  52690
```

Question is how can I join the `locationID` to the `programID` ?

So far I have tried this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#locationsID') IS NOT NULL 
     DROP TABLE #locationsID

SELECT DISTINCT
    LEFT(RTRIM(LocationID), 4) AS Location_ID, LocationName 
INTO
    #locationsID
FROM
    locationstable
ORDER BY
    LocationID 

--select * from #locationsID 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#locomparison') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #locomparison 

SELECT DISTINCT 
    cloc.LocationID, pfm.programID as programID 
INTO
    #locomparison
FROM
    #locationsID  cloc
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    tablewithlivesystemdata pfm ON pfm.programID = cloc.Location_ID
ORDER BY
    LocationID

--Main
SELECT
    programID, LocationID, * 
FROM
    Students
JOIN
    #locomparison ON LocationID.#locomparison = programID.#Students
```

But this is not working :(

Comment: What are the datatypes of programID and locationID? And when you said not working, are you having error or executing but not getting the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You can match on part of the string. If locationID is 5 characters long, the following left function returns the 4 leftmost characters.

```
select s.programID, l.LocationID
from #students s
join #Locations l on s.programID = LEFT(LocationID, LEN(LocationID)-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If programID and locationID are both INTeger type, you use CAST()

```
SELECT *
  FROM #students s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN #Locations l 
    ON s.programID = CAST(LEFT(CAST(locationID AS VARCHAR(50)),4) AS INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these columns are VARCHAR you can use LIKE condition:

```
select s.programID, l.LocationID
from #students s
join #Locations l on l.LocationID LIKE s.programID + '%';
```

If they are INT you should convert them to VARCHAR first:

```
select s.programID, l.LocationID
from #students s
join #Locations l on convert(varchar(50), l.LocationID) LIKE convert(varchar(50), s.programID) + '%';
```

Alternatively, if LocationID is always 10x bigger than ProgramID you can use:

```
select s.programID, l.LocationID
from #students s
join #Locations l on l.LocationID = s.programID * 10;
```